# Dynamic concat with pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, concatenation

I have to write a function that concats two integer arrays. The values of the second array should be attached to the first array. In my assignment the header of the function is given:

```
void concatArrays(int *numbers1, int length1, int *numbers2, int length2)
```

I wanted to to that by dynamically expand the size of the first array with realloc and than copy the second array into the new memory. But i can't do that because i have only int* and not the pointer to the pointer. And so I cannot use malloc, calloc or realloc. How could i write such a function without changing the header of the function?

Comment: The destination array has to be pre-allocated by the caller to the sufficient length. And you can't `realloc` the array if it was statically allocated.

Comment: You sure the return type is `void`? In case it is not statically allocated you can call realloc on them(returns of `malloc`, `realloc`)..but no use doing that if it is not returning anything

Comment: Yes the two arrays are allocated before and the return value is void. I have to append the second array to the first with these function parameters.

Comment: Then just append it. If it has insufficient space allocated, then it's the caller problem.

Comment: No, the first has'nt sufficent space, i have to increase it. My question is, is that possible? otherwise there is a error in the assignment.

Comment: @Maxele.: Congrats there is error in assignment. (For sure not a good assignment)

Comment: Thanks. Am I right that with int** numbers1 the allocation in the function is possible?

Comment: @Maxele.: With `int**` you can do it without changing the return type but still there will be one thing that no length variable can be modified. With `int*` you have to return `int*` and same as before no length variable can be modified.

Comment: With the function signature given, the problem is unsolvable. There is no way to indicate where the result is stored. There are all sorts of changes that could be made to make it solvable, but change is a prerequisite for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
void concatArray(int** n1, int l1, int* n2, int l2)
{
  int size = (l1 + l2);
  int *test = realloc(*n1, size * sizeof(int));

  if(test == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }

  *n1 = test;

  for(int i = l1; i < size; i++)
  {
    (*n1)[i] = n2[i - l1];
  }
}
```

I will use this code for the function. The assignment is wrong.

Comment: I'd say making it return `int*` would be preferable. Probably easier to explain to the tutor why you made it return a value than to explain why you changed a parameter like this.

Comment: Also since you marked your question a C, you might want to consider using `memcpy` to append data over manually copying it in a loop.